# Decrypt Kerberos ticket using keytab

Tags: c++, c, linux, kerberos, krb5.ini

I'm looking for an example to decrypt *Kerberos ticket* and get the *username* using `keytab` file.
I came across the library *kerb5*,  and the function `krb5_server_decrypt_ticket_keytab()` looks perfect for the job.

I saw a few examples ([example 1](https://github.com/krb5/krb5/blob/371f09d4bf4ca0c7ba15c5ef909bc35307ed9cc3/src/clients/kvno/kvno.c), [example 2](https://github.com/krb5/krb5/blob/master/src/tests/s4u2proxy.c)) but they require parameters that I do not understand: `ccache`, `type`, etc.

I have 2 parameters: `ticket`(base64 encode) and `keytab` file, but even with the help of these examples I am not sure how to verify the ticket and get the username.

What is `ccache` is used for?

I would love an explanation of the various parameters and how the examples can be run.

Comment: ccahce is the credentials cache, its where the users creds are stored

Comment: also the server's cred cache. You need the servers creds to decrypt - in fact your program is the 'server'

Comment: Even with the links and your explanations of what you are looking for, it would be much better for you to put together a small code attempt to see what works and what does not.  Until that point, there is very little anyone can do or say to help that reading the documentation on this tech will not do better.  If you do decide to attempt some code, and it does not work, then post the attempt here in the form of a [mcve] and point out what the specific problems are.

Comment: You are wasting your time for low level stuff. Use a high level API like GSS-API or SSPI.

Comment: any progress with this?